# Travis CI setting up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up Travis CI for our group project and it doesn't work. When I've added .travis.yml, it gave an error:

```
$ nuget restore SmartVision.sln
Input file does not exist: SmartVision.sln.
The command "nuget restore SmartVision.sln" failed and exited with 1 during
```

I've tried to look other solutions and tried other methods, but it didn't help. Maybe you can help me? Our solution is here: https://github.com/dogecade/ProtingaVizija

**.travis.yml**

```
language: csharp
solution: SmartVision.sln
install: nuget restore SmartVision.sln
```

**SOLUTION**

**.travis.yml**

```
language: csharp
solution: ./SmartVision/SmartVision.sln
install: nuget restore ./SmartVision/SmartVision.sln
```

Comment: Looks like you need to provide the proper path to the .sln file.

Comment: You probably need to use `./SmartVision/SmartVision.sln`

Comment: @trailmax It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @DeividasBrazenas Good stuff. Glad it worked for you. Generally checking paths on CI server is a first thing you do when you get "file not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more details about your .sln file, where is it, i mean maybe you have put it to some folder. your .sln and .yaml should be in one level or in your .yaml file you should specify a full path to your .sln

Comment: You can find it in github solution :)

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: @TharinduLucky new users don't have the option to make a comment on someone else's post